# SQL code has no erros but does not get the data from the database

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli, sql-insert

I am relatively new to PHP and SQL. I am working on a little PHP website which should contain a chat-function. Now I have a table in my database which is called: 'friendchat'. This has five columns: receiver, sender, message, date, message-id. The date column is from the type datetime and message-id is A_I.
So now I wrote the following PHP lines in order to get insert the message into the database. The function 'DB::' is contained in the 'classes/DB.php'. This method of getting and inserting data worked for me every time, but now it doesn't:

```html
    
<?php   
session_start();
include 'classes/DB.php'; 
if (isset($_POST['message-submit'])) { //activation of the send-button
    if(isset($_GET['userchat'])){ //this variable gets the name of the user you want to chat with which you could selected on the previous page
    
    $message = $_POST['message']; //gets the data from the textarea
    
    $receiver_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['userchat'])[0]['id']);  //here i get the userid from the person i am chating to in order to be able to insert him in the friendchat table as receiver
    
    DB::query('INSERT INTO friendchat VALUES (:receiver, :sender, :message, \'\', \'\')', array(':receiver'=>$receiver_id, ':sender'=>$_SESSION['myid'], ':message'=>$_POST['message']));  //now the message,receiver, the sender, datetime and message-id will be inserted into the database
    
}else{
  echo "Unothorized access!";  //illegal access
}
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML form code:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="POST" class="message-form">
      <input class="message" type="text" placeholder="message" name="message">
      <input class="submit" type="submit" name='message-submit' value="Send">
      </form> //form for getting the data from the website
```

So when I run the code I get no error messages or any notices but the data is not in my database. I cant figure out what the problem could be. Can someone please help me? If you need any additional information please ask me.

Comment: Databases usually don’t give error messages by themselves, you have to explicitly _ask_ for them. Please go _read up_ on how you do that with the database class you are using there. Right now you are just firing off the query, but you don’t care _at all_ whether it actually succeeded, and if not why not.

Comment: Always explicitly mention the target columns in an `INSERT`! And in this case you could combine the `SELECT` and the `INSERT` to one statement like `INSERT INTO friendchat (<target columns>) SELECT id, :sender, :message, \'\', \'\' FROM users WHERE username=:username`. That saves you one round trip.

Comment: Enable error reporting in PHP and check what you will get.  Add these on top of your php file ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
session_start();
include 'classes/DB.php'; 
if (isset($_POST['message-submit'])) { //activation of the send-button
    if(isset($_GET['userchat'])){ //this variable gets the name of the user you want to chat with which you could selected on the previous page

$message = $_POST['message']; //gets the data from the textarea

$receiver_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['userchat'])[0]['id']);  //here i get the userid from the person i am chating to in order to be able to insert him in the friendchat table as receiver



var_dump($receiver_id);
```

print out the value of $receiver_id to debug

Are you getting a value for $receiver_id, if not go back a step and var_dump the value contained in '$_GET['userchat'])[0]['id'])'

```
$returnValue = DB::query('INSERT INTO friendchat VALUES (:receiver, :sender, :message, \'\', \'\')', array(':receiver'=>$receiver_id, ':sender'=>$_SESSION['myid'], ':message'=>$_POST['message']));  //now the message,receiver, the sender, datetime and message-id will be inserted into the database

var_dump($returnValue);
```

Save the query result and var_dump it. This will allow you to see if you got a 'true' or 'false' back from the insert

```
die();
```

stop code here so that you can see the var_dump output in your network tab in your web browser (F12 in chrome)

if you got this far without seeing any errors try writing the insert query into phpmyadmin (directly into the database) with the exact values you have in the above variables, if there is something wrong the database should give you a more specific error to work from

```
}else{
  echo "Unothorized access!";  //illegal access
}
}
?>
```